# Huge iptables list, can I reset this?

Tags: iptables, ufw

I've been trying to block an IP that is trying to break into a Wordpress installation on my server. At first I entered a command to drop connections to it using IPTables, but I could still see it hitting successfully in the Apache logs.

Next I tried using the UFW command that should work, but although when I list my UFW status, everything looks fine, but when I do list my iptables file, it's massive. I'm talking about approximately 200 lines of config that are often like this:

```
Chain ufw-user-limit (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 
3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with 
icmp-port-unreachable
```

The config for blocking this IP is near the bottom of the iptables list, but not far enough down. If I do **ufw reset** will it be safe and set my server to a normal state or am I likely to have some weird problems, like suddenly I'll be vulnerable to weird attacks?

Sorry if this is not well asked, I am not smart at this and it's very stressful seeing that IP just hit my xmlrpc.php file over and over in real time.

Answer (score 1):

We can not simply answer such a question. You need to verify your ruleset yourself. For example, we can not tell you that you need to open port X or close port Y.

Flushing your rules may or may not cause troubles to you depending on the rules you are currently using and how they are related to the running services on your server and your clients.

Comment: maybe my question should be: If I delete them all, and there's nothing I specifically ever added (it's a VPS on a big host just running a website), in the typical case, there's nothing that should BREAK right, it just sort of reverts to being a plain server?

Comment: @user3833000 if the default policies are to accept, yes.